# Fit a normal fit in histogram with a x-log scale

Tags: r, histogram, logarithm

I hope some of you help me. I am dealing with a plottiing a normal fit in my histogram with x-log scale. I use log scale because a normal histogram with my data has a long tail. My codes are like this..

```
breaks<- c(0,0.01, 0.05, 0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200,300) #bins
major <- c(0.1,1,10,100)

H <- hist(log10(B),plot=B) #using data "B"

plot(H$mids,H$counts,type="n",
  xaxt="n",
  xlab="B",ylab="Counts",
  main="Histogram of B",
  bg="lightgrey"
)
abline(v=log10(breaks),col="lightgrey",lty=2)
abline(v=log10(major),col="lightgrey")
abline(h=pretty(H$counts),col="lightgrey")
plot(H,add=T,freq=T,col="blue")
#Position of ticks
at <- log10(breaks)

#Creation X axis
axis(1,at=at,labels=10^at)
curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean(B), sd=sd(B)), add=TRUE) # 1st try
lines(density(B))  # 2nd try

xfit<-seq(min(B),max(B),length=40) # 3rd try
yfit<-dnorm(xfit,mean=mean(B),sd=sd(B)) 
yfit<-yfit*diff(H$mids[1:2])*length(B) 
lines(xfit, yfit, col="red", lwd=2)
```

But 1st, 2nd, 3rd tries did not work..Please let me know how to add a normal fit into my histogram.  Thank you very much for your help. 
Summy

Answer (score 2):

I just changed your first try so that you get what you want:

```
B <- rlnorm(10000)
H <- hist(log10(B), freq = FALSE, col="blue", xaxt="n", xlab="B") 
at <- H$mids
axis(1,at=at,labels=round(10^at,2))
curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean(log10(B)), sd=sd(log10(B))), add=TRUE)
```

Hope it helps,

alex

Comment: Thanks, Alex. It works, but I want to put my initially "B" numbers in x-axis, not the log(B). Is there any other way?

Comment: I edited my answer - I thought that this part was already solved in your question. In my answer I only changed `freq=FALSE` in `hist` and added the `log10` as needed in the `dnorm`

Comment: @user2928318, if alko's answer address your question properly, consider accepting it by clicking on the green checkmark under the vote arrows. Tks.